# How to access to tensorflow from Jupyter notebook?

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-18.04

I installed tensorflow 2.0 from source, following the official instructions: 
 https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source 
It works when I access from python console (Outside of tensorflow folder), I want to get access from Jupyter notebook.

I copied tensorflow's folder to:

```
/home/kati/anaconda3/pkgs/tensorflow
```

but still not working

```
ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d6579f534729> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

#### System Info

Ubuntu 18.04.3 
jupyter core     : 4.5.0 
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps:

1. Download Anaconda
2. Create a virtual environment and activate it
3. Install K̵e̵r̵a̵s̵ ̵a̵n̵d̵ TensorFlow etc.
4. Launch Jupyter Notebook

Since you already have Jupyter Notebook, you will need to create an env variable, install tensorflow and keras. Commands are mentioned below:

## update conda in your default environment

$ conda upgrade --all

## create a new environment with conda

$ conda create -n [my-env-name] python=[python-version]

## activate the environment you created

$ source activate [my-env-name]

## install pip in the virtual environment

$ conda install pip

## install Tensorflow CPU version

$ pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow # for python 3.*

## install Keras (Note: please install TensorFlow first)

$ pip install Keras

## remove an environment

$ conda env remove --name [my-env-name]

Install pip package and then you can just use "pip install [package name]" command to install any package easily.

Comment: Good answer. However, if you want to use a specific virtual environment in a Jupyter notebook, you need to register the virtualenv as Jupyter kernel: Inside the virtual environment, you need to install the `ipykernel package`: ` pip install ipykernel` . Then you need to register your virtual environment as kernel with `ipython kernel install --user --name=projectname`. `projectname` is the name by which your kernel/virtualenv will appear in Jupyter. Now, whenever you start Jupyter, you'll be able to use your virtualenvironment with tensorflow as kernel.

Comment: I followed those steps but when I lunch python in my console and import tensorflow I get Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Answer (score 0):

Did you start running jupyter notebook from the virtual environment which you installed tensorflow?

Also you don't need to copy tensorflow to anaconda3 folder it's better to install by using pip or anconda navigator.

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Reference:
https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/

Comment: No, I just clone git repo and configure it. I had an old CPU so tensorflow 2.0 not works directly using pip or conda

Comment: Even if you download source code and configure later you need to install using pip don't you? After configuring it you need to install by: `pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-version-tags.whl`

Comment: Yes I did, but I get this error : ERROR: tensorflow-2.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
 my console: